# Why won't FrameMaker output bold text in my document?

Tags: text, pdf, export

Sorry, I'm new here, I hope that this is the right place for my question.

In my document, I have a lot of tables with bold text. I just noticed that when I generate the PDF, the bold text is not there. There is bold text in paragraphs of text, but not in my tables.

Here is that it looks like in FrameMaker:

[image: table with bold text]

Here is what the PDF looks like:

[image: table without bold text]

Any ideas of what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a font issue.

The screen font has no printer counterpart so a substitute font has been used.

or

The font is not licensed to be embeddable (legally) in the PDF so a substitute font has been used.

Fix:

Use an embeddable font.

or

Install the printer/outline font required by the printer corresponding to the screen font.

Comment: The font being used in the tables is Arial Narrow. The outputted font is Arial Narrow. The paragraph style weight is set to bold.

Comment: Could this be the problem? https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/arial-narrow-unavailable-incomplete-cs.html

Comment: I changed the font to something else (I think it looks better anyway) and now it's working.